# Understanding Line Integrals via a simple illustration

Tags: calculus, line-integrals

I am approaching line integrals for the first time. To understand how they work and, most importantly, how they could be used, I tried to come up with simple examples.

One such example is to use line integrals in order to recover the area of the unit square $[0,1]^2$ on $R^2$, which is trivially equal to 1x1=1.

The canonical way to do that is via Riemann integrals:

$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 1\  d \tilde x \ d \tilde y =1$

That is, integrating a measure of 1 over the unit square.

A different approach could use a line integral. Intuitively we could use the linear function $y=ax$ as a `windshield wiper' to get the area of the square.

[animation of the wiper here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/123685/wiper.swf)

Below an attempt to compute the first half of the area by having the slope go from $a=0$ to $a=1$. Let $x(t)=t$ and $y(t)=at$. I get that the area is the "sum" of the integrals of a family of linear functions $y=ax$:

$\int_{0}^1 \int_{c(a)} 1 \ ds \ da  $

where $c(a)={\{ (\tilde x , \tilde y \}:\tilde  y=a\cdot\tilde x \text { and } (\tilde y,\tilde x) \in [0,1]^2 }$. Soving leads to

$\int_0^1 \int_0^1 1 \sqrt{1^2+a^2}dt \ da = \int_{0}^1 \frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{a^2+1}
   a+\sinh ^{-1}(a)\right)da = \frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{2}+\sinh
   ^{-1}(1)\right) \not = 1/2.$

What am I missing? Thanks for helping me understand.

Comment: You can't write a line integral as a double integral, that will give the volume beneath a surface. What you want is the cross sectional area under the function, which can be visualized like this: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/42/Line_integral_of_scalar_field.gif

Comment: I don't want to try to figure out how to find the volume of a cube with such a parameterization but as far as illustrating line integrals go, it doesn't get much better than what I have linked above.

Comment: There is a mistake here: you don't get the volume of a cube by integrating the function $1$ on a square. You integrate $1$ on the whole cube, that is with a 3-dimensional integral, not with a 2-dimensional one.

Comment: @AlexM you are right, I meant the area of the square. I corrected the question accordingly.